# Unmarshal xml with UTF-16 content how to remove special character from bottom of xml file

Tags: java, unicode, xml-parsing, unmarshalling, utf-16

I have an XML which contain some XML data that I am trying to unmarshal but there some special character at the bottom of the XML file and
that contain me an issue and it is throwing an error

```
**org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: Content is not allowed in trailing section.**
```

**if I tried to remove this character manually then it works fine for me.**

But my question is **how to remove that special character from file with runtime**.

I tried the following the way

[image]

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(VariablePack.class);
Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

InputStream is1= new FileInputStream("C:\\temp\\temop4.xml");

Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(is1);
SomeJavaClass someJavaClass = (SomeJavaClass) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);
```

sample XML file data at the bottom there is a special character

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" standalone="no" ?>
<NewStudioVariablePack>
  <projectName>ContextView_NG</projectName>
  <threadID>100015</threadID>
  <gSYSInstance>8</gSYSInstance>
  <variablesList>
    <contextVariables>
       <variable>
        <variableName>C.UserXML</variableName>
        <variableType>B</variableType>
        <variablePicture/>
        <blobType/>
        <value/>
      </variable>
      <variable>
        <variableName>C.sys.RemoteUser</variableName>
        <variableType>A</variableType>
        <variablePicture>30</variablePicture>
        <blobType/>
        <value/>
      </variable>
    </contextVariables>
  </variablesList>

</NewStudioVariablePack>
਍
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to read the file with the normal BufferedReader line by line and skip the last line, but that is not recommended to parse an XML. Just to see if you can read that character on this way.

How does this character get there? Maybe you are using the wrong encoding.

Otherwise set a try/catch block around the parsing code, so at least it won’t crash.

Comment: I am getting this file from some third party server that I am parsing and that file contains a special character. and adding try/catch not going to solve my problem because I have to unmarshal it

Comment: Since it's an 8-bit CRLF, it looks some routine thinks it's a good idea to always append a CRLF when the file doesn't end with one. I think it's safe to test for and remove only this particular value.